Xcode16 crash on launch: dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
My app works fine on Xcode 15.2.
But when I build the same code with Xcode16-Beta, it crashes on start up.( Note no build errors occurred)
Here is the log of the crash:
dyld[1113]: Library not loaded: @rpath/lib/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
  Referenced from: <2432AA10-C4BA-31BD-A431-D32CA47C636D> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/81AB71D9-5B1C-4FA8-931A-CC632FCF4E93/MyAppName.app/MyAppName.debug.dylib
  Reason: tried: '/usr/lib/system/introspection/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/usr/lib/swift/lib/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), 
'/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/lib/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/81AB71D9-5B1C-4FA8-931A-CC632FCF4E93/MyAppName.app/Frameworks/lib/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/81AB71D9-5B1C-4FA8-931A-CC632FCF4E93/MyAppName.app/Frameworks/lib/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/81AB71D9-5B1C-4FA8-931A-CC632FCF4E93/MyAppName.app/lib/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/lib/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), 
'/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/lib/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/81AB71D9-5B1C-4FA8-931A-CC632FCF4E93/MyAppName.app/Frameworks/lib/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/81AB71D9-5B1C-4FA8-931A-CC632FCF4E93/MyAppName.app/Frameworks/lib/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/81AB71D9-5B1C-4FA8-931A-CC632FCF4E93/MyAppName.app/lib/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/lib/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), 
'/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/lib/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/81AB71D9-5B1C-4FA8-931A-CC632FCF4E93/MyAppName.app/Frameworks/lib/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib' (no such file), 
'/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/81AB71D9-5B1C-4FA8-931A-CC632FCF4E93/MyAppName.app/Frameworks/lib/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib' (no such file)

Xcode16 crash on launch: dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib

Any idea why it is behaving like this in Xcode16 Beta?

Welcome to stackoverflow. Please have a read of the [ask] section of the [help]. I would also recommend you take the [tour]. You should provide [mre].

Minimal reproducible example is anything that links to CoreGraphics.tbd.

But this is not stated anywhere in the question. This does not help the future readers, which is main purpose of this site [ask].

I have faced the same problem. I have edited the question to maybe salvage it.

Solution worked for me ...

Minimum deployment target: 15
Minimum deployment target for all pods: 15
Using Charts? minimum deployment target 13

My configuration M1 Sanoma 14.5

I am getting the same error. My setup is M1 Sonoma as well. How did you set Minimum deployment target for all pods to 15?

https://ibb.co/7pbYmcX @LazyNinja

@SandeepMaurya can you explain more? I don't know how to open that context menu which you are showing.

https://ibb.co/jTQH03r @Mistic92

Got it ! Thank you +1

This is a great question, I've encountered this error on Xcode 16 Beta too.
It's an Xcode configuration issue and Apple engineers are looking into it: https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/756658
The workaround is to bump iOS deployment target to 13.

"This is a great question" - it is a long time since you have read [ask] section of the [help]? If you think it will help future readers, you are experienced enough to improve the OP to meet SO guidelines. Otherwise is better off to be deleted IMO.

In my case I went to Pods > Targets > KingFisher > Build Settings. Then under Deployment I changed the iOS Deployment Target to 15.0. Then Clean Build Folder under the Product Menu.
